# Anime where a girl tries to heal a boy with extensions from her body

Tags: story-identification, anime

I only know a specific scene from the anime. A girl wakes up on a roof bleeding and sees a boy badly hurt across from her. Extensions from her body attempt to heal the boy, but then some planes fly overhead and shoot at her, breaking her bond with the boy.

She attempts to crawl to the boy and leaves a trail of blood behind her while doing so. She collapses just before she reaches the boy. The boy wakes up and tells her not to die, but she turns into a crystal and shatters in his arms.

Answer (score 6):

This sounds a lot like a major character death in the anime [Guilty Crown](https://myanimelist.net/anime/10793/Guilty_Crown). The full clip of this death is on YouTube:

and it matches exactly as you described. Those "extensions" you describe are her unique power.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the anime you remember, but I remember the anime *[S-CRY-ed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-CRY-ed)* had a teenage female character, [Schleris Adjani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S-CRY-ed_characters),  who had healing powers and who died in the last episode or right before it using her healing powers.

### Episode 23 - Schleris Adjani

Comment: I added a link to the scene in YouTube. She grows wings before some turrets gun her down.

Comment: Hi! Thank you but it’s not the anime I remember! The style of the anime was much more modern and the scene specifically happened on a roof! Thank you both so much tho :)